# Why is there no ICMP instruction?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-bytecode

As some of you might know, we have a ton of opcodes for comparing different types of primitive values:

```
LCMP
FCMPL
FCMPG
DCMPL
DCMPG
IFEQ
IFNE
IFLT
IFGE
IFGT
IFLE
IF_ICMPEQ
IF_ICMPNE
IF_ICMPLT
IF_ICMPGE
IF_ICMPGT
IF_ICMPLE
IF_ACMPEQ
IF_ACMPNE
...
```

For obvious reasons the creators of the instruction set did not bother to add all `IF_LCMPEQ`, `IF_FCMPLT`, ... instructions, but I am wondering why there is no `ICMP` instruction, seeing that it would be very useful especially for booleans or `Integer.compare(int, int)`.

Comment: It's a six of one, half dozen of the other thing; it doesn't really matter what bytecode is used.  (And `Long.compare` doesn't use lcmp directly; it's just that <, >, etc. on longs is implemented in terms of lcmp.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>There are already two "primarily opinion based" close votes. Indeed, nobody can give a definite answer here, and there may be some handwaving involved when trying to argue about a decision that a bunch of engineers made 25 years ago. But I'll give it a try...</sub>

First of all, I think that the question is justified: The `int` type is the most "prominent" type in the Java Language (last but not least because of its role as an array index). This goes hand in hand with its special role in the Java Virtual Machine, where all (smaller) integral types that are present in the language, like `byte` or `short`, are effectively converted into `int` for all computations. Or, as mentioned in the [Java Virtual Machine Specification, Section 2.11.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.7):

> Because of its emphasis on int comparisons, the Java Virtual Machine provides a rich complement of conditional branch instructions for type `int`.

Now it is reasonable to ask why this "rich complement" seems to **exclude** an instruction that is equivalently present for all other types.

---

The main reason why there is no `icmp` instruction may be that it is neither necessary, nor beneficial.

The suggested application case of using it for `Integer#compare(int, int)` can hardly count as an argument: The implementation of such a method (even if an `icmp` existed) would not be

```
return icmp, arg0, arg1;
```

The translation of a method into bytecode can be rather complex, and given the possibilities of *the Java Language itself*, such a method anyhow has to be implemented equivalently as

```
if (x > y) return 1;
if (x < y) return -1;
return 0;
```

which obviously is can be translated into a sequence of the existing `if_icmp<?>` instructions.

Here, one should keep in mind that the main purpose of these comparison instructions is *branching*: They cause a *jump* to a different location. They are not intended for pushing a value on the stack that could then be "used as a return value of a method". Talking about the *language* and talking about the *virtual machine* are two completely different things here.

---

One might also turn the question around, and ask: Why *are* there `lcmp`, `fcmp_` and `dcmp_` instructions available for `long`, `float` and `double`, respectively?

Here, a definite answer is far easier: Offering the whole set of `eq`, `ne`, `lt`, `le`, `gt` and `ge` comparision instructions for `long`, `float` and `double` would imply 18 additional instructions (or even more, with the `NaN` treatment for the floating point types). That's a lot, considering that there is a hard limit of 256 instructions that are possible with one byte.

By offering the `lcmp`, `fcmp_` and `dcmp_` instructions for these types, the remaining instructions that are available for `int` can be used to *emulate* all the other possible comparison situations. But again, these are mainly intended for *branching*, so there simply is no need for an `icmp` instruction, because for `int`, all necessary branching instructions ("jump conditions") are already available.

Comment: The point of the Integer.compare argument was that an hypothetical compiler could use the ICMP instruction to inline this method while avoiding heavy Bytecode.

Comment: @Clashsoft Sure, no offense :-) One could indeed imagine that an `icmp` that is translated to store the result in the `EAX` register (as a return value on x86) or in an arbitrary register (when inlining) could be beneficial. But here, I think one would have to argue about the question whether the actual (usually register-based) *target machine* has an instruction that is equivalent to an `icmp`, and about the translation process between the *virtual* machine and the *actual* machine code. Again, it's hard to find "THE" answer here, so these are just some (hopefully convincing) arguments...